# Swift 3.0 converting error fix

Tags: core-graphics, swift3, cgrect

I have a swift 2.2 project. 
Now I upgraded it to Swift 3.0 but I have some errors.

```
open var gridClippingRect: CGRect
{
    var contentRect = viewPortHandler?.contentRect ?? CGRect.zero
    contentRect.insetInPlace(dx: 0.0, dy: -(self.axis?.gridLineWidth ?? 0.0) / 2.0)
    return contentRect
}
```

error: Value of type 'CGRect' has no member 'insetInPlace'

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the docs for `CGRect`, the closest method is `insetBy:dx:dy:` which returns a new `CGRect`. So the following code should work for you:

```
contentRect = contentRect.insetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -(self.axis?.gridLineWidth ?? 0.0) / 2.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The error just fixed. Can you help another error (Swift 3.0) also? Now I have many errors in my updated project.